# Need assistance posting data to asp.net mvc application using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tcptrace-pocketsoap

I've got an MVC application that accepts eitherJSON or XML objects dpending on the request type.  This application is based on [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/03/create-rest-api-using-asp-net-mvc-that-speaks-both-json-and-plain-xml.aspx)

To call a method on the MVC application that requires a complex object, I use the following Javascript (JQuery):

```
function GetUnassignedJob() {
if (isInteger($('#txtDay').val()) && isInteger($('#txtMonth').val()) && isInteger($('#txtYear').val()) && isInteger(intCurrentJobSummaryIndex) && intCurrentJobSummaryIndex > -1) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'http://server/api/wip/joboptimise/getlistforids/' + $('#txtYear').val() + '/' + $('#txtMonth').val() + '/' + $('#txtDay').val(),
        data: $.toJSON(aJobSummary[intCurrentJobSummaryIndex].JobIds),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) { ShowLoading(); },
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            try {
                ClearUnassignedJobs();
                AddUnassignedJobs(data);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert('GetUnassignedJob():\r\n\r\n' + e.message);
                HideLoading();
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            HideLoading();
            ShowStatus('unable to retrieve job list');
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
            HideLoading();
        }
    });
}
else {
    ShowStatus('please ensure you have entered numeric values for day, month and year');
}
```

}

When deployed to the server and accessed from any client on the network - everything works fine.  However, when I try to to the same from the server, I receive the following error message:

Page Location: /api/wip/joboptimise/getlistforids/2010/3/10

Message: Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None'  with name '', namespace ''.

Source: System.ServiceModel.Web

Method: System.Object InternalReadObject(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Boolean)

Stack Trace:    at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
   at rbm.api.ObjectFilter.ProcessJson(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)

Some further investigation shows that the InputStream property of the HttpContext is empty!  Stranger still, when I use an application like TcpTrace (so that I can see the HTTP traffic), everything works!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated,

Mark

Comment: Have you tried just using a simple json object in your "data:"? How about just send plain text? What does the controller code look like?

Comment: The problem is that no data is sent when accessed from the server - the content type is set correctly, however the content length is 0.  If I copy and paste the url from the server to the client everything is fine

Comment: So when you debug in visual studio does it ever get to your controller code?

Comment: It does get through to the controller code and executes as if null had been passed for that particular parameter - the business logic allows for this.  I've just noticed that when I use localhost, instead of the server name, on the server that everything works fine - how could this make a difference?

Comment: I had faced a similar issue so the Model which the view requires is not found by the Compiler and hence the error. The issue is that the app is not deployed properly try to publish the web app again.

Answer (score 0):

The prior comments are right, using local host.  You could edit your hosts file located at:
windows\system32\drivers\etc on your server and add an entry that maps local host to the URL

```
 127.0.0.1 www.xyz.com
```